# Retornar algo na consulta quando não houver registros

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Estou realizando ajustes em um sistema de gráficos, basicamente existe uma consulta no banco para trazer valores e popular o gráfico, porem quando não há um registro específico não retorna nada do banco e o gráfico quebra.

Eu gostaria que quando não houvesse registro pelo menos trouxesse os campos com valores zerados, é possível?

Obs.:
Utilizo o MySQL. 
Os gráficos são em JS, após a consulta transformo ele em JSON para o gráfico consumir.

Exemplo:
`select nome from clientes`

Se tiver registro e eu converter para JSON ficará assim mais ou menos:

```
{nome: fulano, nome: ciclano}
```

Porém se não haver registro fica assim:

`{}`

E eu gostaria assim pelo menos:

```
{nome: ""}
```

Mas só me interessaria se fosse uma solução do banco, não sei se é possível.

Comment: Este gráfico é de qual linguagem/teconologia? Pergunto pelo fato de fazer este tratamento do outro lado.

Comment: Olá @Douglas é JS

Comment: Favor postar sua query, além disso talvez seja melhor controlar isso na propria aplicação e não no banco de dados

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida após a consulta transformo o resultado em JSON para o gráfico, porem se não há registro não existe JSON para o gráfico

Comment: Então, você pode retornar um json vazio qnd n tiver dados para o filtro e na aplicação fazer um tratamento para isso informando que n teve resultados

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno então seria algo assim: `se resultado == vazio então mostra mensagem persoanlizada senão mostra resultado`.

Comment: Então, é que gostariam que o gráfico pelo menos aparece algo mesmo zerado, vejo como solução quando estiver vazio, simular um JSON com zeros, a dúvida era se o SQL tinha algo sobre, mas valeu

Answer (score 1):

vc pode fazer um IF dentro do seu SELECT
como vc não postou os campos. segue esse exemplo
espero ter ajudado.

TABELA:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| book_id | book_name                           | isbn_no     | cate_id | aut_id | pub_id | dt_of_pub  | pub_lang | no_page | book_price |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| BK001   | Introduction to Electrodynamics     | 0000979001  | CA001   | AUT001 | P003   | 2001-05-08 | English  |     201 |      85.00 |
| BK002   | Understanding of Steel Construction | 0000979002  | CA002   | AUT002 | P001   | 2003-07-15 | English  |     300 |     105.50 |
| BK003   | Guide to Networking                 | 0000979003  | CA003   | AUT003 | P002   | 2002-09-10 | Hindi    |     510 |     200.00 |
| BK004   | Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | 0000979004  | CA002   | AUT004 | P004   | 2004-02-16 | English  |     600 |     250.00 |
| BK005   | Conceptual Physics                  | 0000979005  | CA001   | AUT005 | P006   | 2003-07-16 | NULL     |     345 |     145.00 |
| BK006   | Fundamentals of Heat                | 0000979006  | CA001   | AUT006 | P005   | 2003-08-10 | German   |     247 |     112.00 |
| BK007   | Advanced 3d Graphics                | 0000979007  | CA003   | AUT007 | P002   | 2004-02-16 | Hindi    |     165 |      56.00 |
| BK008   | Human Anatomy                       | 0000979008  | CA005   | AUT008 | P006   | 2001-05-17 | German   |      88 |      50.50 |
| BK009   | Mental Health Nursing               | 0000979009  | CA005   | AUT009 | P007   | 2004-02-10 | English  |     350 |     145.00 |
| BK010   | Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | 0000979010  | CA002   | AUT010 | P007   | 2002-10-14 | English  |     400 |     225.00 |
| BK011   | The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | 0000979011  | CA004   | AUT011 | P005   | 2007-06-09 | French   |     225 |      95.00 |
| BK012   | The Nature  of World                | 0000979012  | CA004   | AUT005 | P008   | 2005-12-20 | English  |     350 |      88.00 |
| BK013   | Environment a Sustainable Future    | 0000979013  | CA004   | AUT012 | P001   | 2003-10-27 | German   |     165 |     100.00 |
| BK014   | Concepts in Health                  | 0000979014  | CA005   | AUT013 | P004   | 2001-08-25 | NULL     |     320 |     180.00 |
| BK015   | Anatomy & Physiology                | 0000979015  | CA005   | AUT014 | P008   | 2000-10-10 | Hindi    |     225 |     135.00 |
| BK016   | Networks and Telecommunications     | 00009790_16 | CA003   | AUT015 | P003   | 2002-01-01 | French   |      95 |      45.00 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+





mysql> SELECT book_name,
    -> IF(pub_lang="English", "Engllish Book", "Other Lnaguage")
    -> AS Language
    -> FROM book_mast;
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| book_name                           | Language       |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Introduction to Electrodynamics     | Engllish Book  | 
| Understanding of Steel Construction | Engllish Book  | 
| Guide to Networking                 | Other Lnaguage | 
| Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | Engllish Book  | 
| Conceptual Physics                  | Other Lnaguage | 
| Fundamentals of Heat                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Advanced 3d Graphics                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Human Anatomy                       | Other Lnaguage | 
| Mental Health Nursing               | Engllish Book  | 
| Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | Engllish Book  | 
| The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | Other Lnaguage | 
| The Nature  of World                | Engllish Book  | 
| Environment a Sustainable Future    | Other Lnaguage | 
| Concepts in Health                  | Other Lnaguage | 
| Anatomy & Physiology                | Other Lnaguage | 
| Networks and Telecommunications     | Other Lnaguage | 
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

EXEMPLO RETIRADO DO SEGUINTE SITE:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, e se não haver registros o que retorna?

Answer (score 0):

Quando receber os dados do servidor, você pode normalizar a saída no javascript. Um exemplo seria algo como:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '',
        method: 'GET'
}).success(function(data){
   // caso o retorno seja vazio
   if (data.length == 0){
       data.atributo1 = 0;
       data.atributo2 = 0;
       // definir todos os atributos usado no grafico
   }
}).error(function(data){});
```